# If statement fails with $(this), but works with absolute

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I ran into this very odd scenario. 
This won't hide the H1:

```
if ($('#content h1').hasClass('active')) {
    $(this).hide();
}
```

Only this will:

```
if ($('#content h1').hasClass('active')) {
    $('#content h1').hide();
}
```

Why can't I use the (this)? Is something wrong with the script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the correct behaviour. In the context of your `if` statement `this` does not hold a reference to your `h1` element but to the `document` element (or function if you are inside of a function).

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
$('#content h1').foreach(function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

In this case, as Jan explained, this will be in the context you expect it to be (the heading element).

Answer (score 0):

What you want is probably

```
var h1 = $('#content h1')
if (h1).hasClass('active')) {
    h1.hide();
}
```

your "this" will, as stated above, not reference your object.

Comment: More simple and performant would be

$('#content h1.active').hide();

Answer (score 0):

The statement `$('#content h1').hasClass('active')` returns a Boolean value (true or false), as opposed to a jQuery object, which is what you're trying to use `$(this)` for. See the usage of `hasClass` [here](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/).

If you're trying to perform an action on all elements that match a certain selector, give this selector a try instead:

```
$("#content h1.active").hide();
```

This finds all elements with an `id` attribute of "content" that contain an `h1` element with a `class` attribute of "active," and hides them all.